# What is execution process of 'case when' in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

```
case    when contact_number1 ='' or contact_number2 is null then contact_number1 
        when contact_number1 ='' or contact_number1 is null then contact_number2 
        when contact_number1 is not null and contact_number2 is not null then   concat(contact_number1,',',contact_number2) 
end
```

If first case is true then it executes first case then it goes to next case statement or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement has 3 rows of conditions.

If the first row of conditions are met, yes, it will also try to see if the second row is met, and so on. Think of each row as an independent set of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html), I do not believe that all conditions are executed - it executes the first statement whose condition is met, and skips all others.

Relevant part of the documentation:

> CASE clauses can be used wherever an expression is valid. Each condition is an expression that returns a boolean result. If the condition's result is true, the value of the CASE expression is the result that follows the condition, and the remainder of the CASE expression is not processed

Comment: You should also include the note at the end of that section: "*As described in Section 4.2.14, there are various situations in which subexpressions of an expression are evaluated at different times, so that the principle that "CASE evaluates only necessary subexpressions" is not ironclad. For example a constant 1/0 subexpression will usually result in a division-by-zero failure at planning time, even if it's within a CASE arm that would never be entered at run time*"

Comment: Ah, missed that part, but it makes sense - planning still checks the conditions and can error out, execution short-circuits - thanks for noticing and added that!